# Running NUnit in Mono with Jenkins

Tags: mono, jenkins, nunit

I'm sorry if this is already answered in another place, but I can not find anything after an hour searching google.

I have a Jenkins CI environment set up on a Ubuntu server.  Right now it successfully compiles  c# code with the help of mono.  I'd like it to also be able to run NUnit tests.

What's the best way to do this?
Is there a way that does not include a slave'd windows version of Jenkins, perhaps with nunit-console? (Would be cool if after running that command, I could view results via Jenkins' web interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I figured it out with a little tinkering.

I configured the jenkins job under Build and added a 'Execute shell' command of

```
nunit-console "$WORKSPACE/path/to/Tests.dll"
```

and then later as a post build event, I picked up the resulting xml (With the NUnit plugin for jenkins) and it displays it all in the web interface.

One note of caution, this is a -really- simple project, so I don't know if that will all work under mono with more advanced tests etc.